# Show that these two integrals are the same

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to prove this. Where do I start?
$$ \int_{0}^{x}\Biggl[\int_{0}^{t} F(u)\,du\Biggr]dt = \int_{0}^{x}(x-u)F(u)\,du$$

Comment: Differentiate both sides with respect to x. Show that both sides’ results are equal. Then you just have to check both original sides for one value of x.

Comment: Am i using the fundamental theorem of calc?

Comment: Yes use FTC. Note that differentiating the right hand side wrt x doesn’t give zero — there is a product rule there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integration by parts using  $u=\int_{0}^{t}{F}(u)du\quad ,dv=dt$
$$=\left. t\int_{0}^{t}{F}(u)du \right|_{0}^{x}-\int_{0}^{x}{tF\left( t \right)dt}=x\int_{0}^{x}{F}(u)du-\int_{0}^{x}{tF\left( t \right)dt}=\int_{0}^{x}{\left( x-t \right)F\left( t \right)dt}$$